# Is there a way to set mobs to target a player no matter if they are passive or aggressive?

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

Is there a way to set mobs to target a player no matter if they are passive or aggressive?

I have tried converting the mob to a creature then using the setTarget() method, however, that is bugged in the spigot API and does not work. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So I'd suggest you to make the mob for example a Zombie, but only serverside. So the server will calculate that the zombie targets the player, but the player will see, for example a harmless pig.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your desired Listener to avoid being attacked by hostile mobs:

```
@EventHandler
public void onEntityTarget(EntityTargetLivingEntityEvent event){
    event.setCancelled(true);
}
```

Note: Make sure you restrict the entity type - like this, no hostile mob attacks any entity.

Found the solution [here](https://bukkit.org/threads/making-hostile-mobs-passive-as-in-creative.270941/).